# Why does Billy shut down Lucy during deposition?

Tags: plot-explanation, goliath

In Goliath season 1, during the first deposition of Ned, Billy is very disruptive to Lucy when she is trying to conduct the deposition. This ultimately leads to Callie taking over and she proceeds to do very well which turns out badly for Billy.

Billy obviously knew Callie and her abilities, so why did he do this? I'd assume that he was doing it to make Donald mad, but I don't recall Billy knowing anything about Lucy/Donald.

Did he do it on purpose to get Callie to take over or was he just being difficult and it backfired on him?